# Is there a better way to connect to multiple BLE devices in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on `BLE` (bluetooth) in `Android`. I have found information via Google. It seems `Android` can be connected to `multiple BLE device` by using multiple `BluetoothGatt` like the following pseudo code.

I have multiple **BLE devices**. I think I need to define multiple `BluetoothGatt` parameters first.

```
private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGattA = null, 
     mBluetoothGattB = null , mBluetoothGattC = null;
```

The First BLE device connection.

```
final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address_A);
mBluetoothGattA = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
```

Try to connected to the second BLE device.

```
final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address_B);
mBluetoothGattB = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
```

Am I right? If I connect to the 6 BLE devices, should I define 6 `BluetoothGatt` parameters?

Is there a smart way to connect to multiple BLE  device ?

Comment: Do you find any example for the same. can you guide me how to connect multiple BLE devices

Answer (score 1):

Is not necesary multiple BluetoothGattCallback. Accidentally I connect two BLE devices using the same BluetoothGattCallback and works fine .

In the BluetoothGattCallback you must to know the address of the device that send data.

For example you can use :

```
gatt.getDevice().getAddress();
```

Hope this help

Answer (score -1):

You are going to handle each BLE device by creating each BluetoothGattCallback for each one (maximum 7 right now). for example like:

```
private final BluetoothGattCallback oneGattcallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() ...
```

`private final BluetoothGattCallback twoGattcallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() ...`

then try to connect
`mBluetoothGattA = deviceA.connectGatt(this, false, oneGattcallback );`
 and `mBluetoothGattB = deviceB.connectGatt(this, false, twoGattcallback );` just like that. you will find a lot examples handle one connection and just develop more for multiple connection.

Comment: Adding multiple callbacks is not a solution. The Android BLE API is designed in a way that a single `BluetoothGattCallback` works for multiple connections. You can handle different devices based on their address in the `BluetoothGattCallback` methods.